# Getting Cloudtrail Cloudwatch Events Working

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, amazon-cloudtrail

Im attempting to process cloudwatch events, specifically cloudtrail ones since I am deploying into us-east-1 but would like to get events from all regions. Everything deploys, but the events are not triggering the lambda.

My cloudtrail is configured for all regions and delivering to a Cloudwatch Log Group.

```
functions:
ec2_instance_region_watch:
handler: ec2_instance_region_watch.ec2_instance_region_watch
events:
- cloudwatchEvent:
event:
source:
- “ec2.amazonaws.com”
detail-type:
- “AWS API Call via CloudTrail”
detail:
eventName:
- “RunInstances”
```

My cloudwatch event is created.

```
{
“detail-type”: [
“AWS API Call via CloudTrail”
],
“source”: [
“ec2.amazonaws.com”
],
“detail”: {
“eventName”: [
“RunInstances”
]
}
}
```

I launch an instance, and in the cloudwatch log group I get an event that contains what I expect.

```
"eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "RunInstances",
```

Yet my lambda never fires, so its not matching the cloudtrail event.

I was trying to somewhat dupe this, https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-cloudtrail-cloudwatch-events/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding Lambda as subscriber from CloudWatch Events Console,
configure the cloudwatch event trigger from Lambda console

Doing this will add "Lambda:Invoke" permission for configured CloudWatch Event.

Alternatively, add the invoke permission manually for CW events to make the invocation using the add-permission method of Lambda.

CLI example

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name FUNCTION_NAME \
--statement-id STATEMENT_ID \
--action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal events.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn "arn:aws:events:<region>:<acct_id>:rule/<rule_name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The CloudWatch Rule Event Pattern source is incorrect. It should be -
"source": ["aws.ec2"]

```
{
"source": [
    "aws.ec2"
],
"detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
],
"detail": {
    "eventSource": [
        "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
        "RunInstances"
    ]
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Cloud

Answer (score 0):

> specifically cloudtrail ones since I am deploying into us-east-1 but would like to get events from all regions.

CloudTrail has two main delivery mechanisms:

1. Trail configuration, and
2. Forwarding to CloudWatch Events.

When you create a multi-region Trail, events from all regions are sent to that one multi-region Trail configuration, i.e., to that unique S3 bucket and CloudWatch Logs Group.

But event forwarding to CloudWatch Events, because it's not part of the Trail configuration, does not work in the same way. Event forwarding is done in region.

Events happening in us-east-1 will be forwarded to CloudWatch Events in us-east-1 and events happening in us-west-2 will be forwarded to CloudWatch Events in us-west-2.

To achieve what you ask, the best approximation would be to create one Lambda function in us-east-1 and then one CloudWatch Events rule per region pointing to the same Lambda function (cross-region) in us-east-1.